# How to vertically align an image in a beamer column?

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

How can I vertically align the content of a `beamer` `column`? In the following example, I want the rule in the second column to be centered vertically.

I could use `\begin{columns}[c]`, but that would vertically align all of the columns. I still want the first and third columns to be top-aligned. I also tried to add `\vfill` in different places to no effect.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{0.33\linewidth}
            This is the first column. This is the first column. 
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\linewidth}
            \centering
            \rule{\linewidth}{1cm}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\linewidth}
            This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. 
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for guessing shifting values. You can let LaTeX do all the calculations for you: use `minipage`s, measure the total height of the right and left `minipage`s, select the maximum height and then use this value in the optional argument for `minipage` to get the desired alignment.

The `\TCTcolumns` will do this; it has three mandatory arguments:

```
\TCTcolumns{<column 1 contents>}{<column 2 contents>}{<column 3 contents>}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newsavebox\myboxa
\newsavebox\myboxb
\newlength\myhta
\newlength\mydpa
\newlength\myhtb
\newlength\mydpb
\newlength\maxht

\newcommand\TCTcolumns[3]{%
\begin{lrbox}{\myboxa}
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
  #1
  \end{minipage}%
\end{lrbox}%
\begin{lrbox}{\myboxb}
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
  #3
  \end{minipage}%
\end{lrbox}% 
\settoheight\myhta{\usebox\myboxa}%
\settodepth\mydpa{\usebox\myboxa}%
\addtolength\myhta{\mydpa}%
\settoheight\myhtb{\usebox\myboxb}%
\settodepth\mydpb{\usebox\myboxb}%
\addtolength\myhtb{\mydpb}%
\setlength\maxht{\myhta}%
\ifdim\myhtb>\myhta
  \setlength\maxht{\myhtb}%
\fi
\begin{minipage}[t][\maxht][t]{0.3\linewidth}
  #1
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t][\maxht][c]{0.3\linewidth}
  #2
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t][\maxht][t]{0.3\linewidth}
  #3
\end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\TCTcolumns{This is the first column. This is the first column.}{\centering\raisebox{0.5\height}{\rule{\linewidth}{1cm}}}{This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you do not mind using a package for the job, you can use `tcolorbox`. Note that you will need the brand-new version `3.30 (2014/11/17)` for this.

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=3,raster equal height,blanker,
    raster column skip=5mm,raster left skip=-5mm,raster right skip=-5mm,
    flushleft upper]
  \tcbitem
    This is the first column. This is the first column.
  \tcbitem[valign=center]
    \rule{\linewidth}{1cm}
  \tcbitem
    This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column.
  \end{tcbitemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

After compiling twice, the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is easy, use `\parbox`. You will have to do some dirty tweak of the actual vertical displacement of the rule.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{0.33\linewidth}
        This is the first column. This is the first column. 
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.33\linewidth}
        \centering
    \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace{2cm}
        \rule{\linewidth}{1cm}}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.33\linewidth}
        This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. This is the third column. 
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```